# Django Login error TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have an issue with  use login on my Django app.  I created a custom user model and it works fine with the database .  Some how the login page is not working , it is expecting Json data. I have no idea why it is doing it to.
I have the following model

```
class AdminAccounts(BaseUserManager):    
    def create_user(self, user, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not user:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(user),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, user, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            user,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, user, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            user,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True,verbose_name='User name') 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='User name',default=None,blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    objects= AdminAccounts()
    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that is built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Email & Password are required by default.
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'adminaccounts'
        verbose_name_plural ="Admin Accounts"
    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.user

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.admin
        
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

The following login views

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):    
    user=forms.CharField(max_length=6)
    password=forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    def clean(self):        
        self.cleaned_data = super().clean()
        #print(self.cleaned_data)  
        return self.cleaned_data

def dologin(request):
    next = ""
    if request.GET:
       next = request.GET['next'] 
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)       
        if form.is_valid():            
            username = form.cleaned_data['user'] 
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)                           
            if user is not None and user.is_active:                
                login(request, user)            
                request.session.create()
                request.session['user']=user                 
                request.session.set_expiry(900)   
                if next == "":                      
                    return redirect(dashboard)
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
            else:                 
                return render(request, 'index.html', {'invalid_authentication': True})           
        else:            
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'invalid_authentication': True})
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'invalid_authentication': False})
```

I am getting the following error  while using the login

```
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable
[22/Dec/2021 09:51:47] "POST /dologin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 104786
```

If I remove the login(request,user) code , it works fine. I  have no idea what I am missing. Can some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a typo  error , on
`request.session['user']=user` .

it must be  as follows

```
request.session['user']=username
```